# How to run jenkins slave on specific Mesos node?

Tags: jenkins, mesos, marathon

I want to run jenkins slave using mesos-plugin in jenkins on Mesos nodes that have:

```
"attributes": {
  "environment": "baremetal"
}
```

so I added in slave configuration in `Mesos Offer Selection Attributes` field:

```
{"environment":"baremetal"}
```

but I cant see this values in

```
dcos task --json mesos-jenkins-32d4cd1dfcf74ab984024b190a881a91-dind-node-npm-6
```

output, so how I can be sure that it really works ?

When I tried to use `"constraints": [["environment", "UNLIKE", "baremetal"]]` slave couldn't start.

Comment: Where exactly did you configure the attributes? Ands did you restart the respective agents?

Comment: I can see these attributes when I do `dcos node --json` ( I am not responsible for configuring Mesos cluster ) and Jenkins slaves are deployed on demand by mesos-plugin in Jenkins.